# Vue change event for checkbox is not working

Tags: html, vue.js

I am using Vue to pass handle the function and when the checkbox is checked, the function is not triggered by the change event. I am not sure whether the problem is because I write it on mounted or anything else.

```
mounted() {
        var self = this;
        let id = this.$route.params.id;

        var chkInfo = [];
        chk.where("partId", "==", id).get()
            .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    var data = doc.data();

                    chkInfo.push({ chk_id: doc.id, d: data.detail, s: data.sequence, status: data.status });
                });

                let html = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < chkInfo.length; i++) {

                    html += `
                            <li class="todo-item">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="" @change="updateTodo()" class="todo-item__checkbox">
                                    <label class="word">${chkInfo[i].d}</label>
                            </li>
                     `;
                }
                self.todoList = html;
            })
    }
```

The template of Vue. I use componentKey to reload the component so that the data can dynamically populate to the interface.

```
<section>
    <label>Checklist:<br/></label>
      <input v-model.trim="newTodo" id="todo-box" placeholder=" Add new todo"/>
       <button type="submit" @click.prevent="addTodo()" class="new-todo-button" :disabled="!todoFilled">Add</button>
           <ul class="todo-list">
               <div v-html="todoList"></div>
               <div v-html="addList" :key="listKey"></div>
           </ul>                      
 </section>
```

Comment: Where have you defined the updateTodo function?..I don't see it

Comment: Yes I wrote it on methods there. Currently, no coding is written in the function except a console log message and the log message does not appear in the console.

Comment: Why don't you use the template section to create the Dom instead of JavaScript

Comment: I create dom in javascript to dynamically populate the interface based on the data obtained from firestore. I tried this method for a small part only. Besides, I already use that method on the whole project, I cannot change the other parts at this moment actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it the Vue way with a template?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(info, index) in chkInfo" :key="index">
      <li class="todo-item">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="info.d" @change="updateTodo(info.d)" class="todo-item__checkbox" />
        <label class="word">{{info.d}}</label>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chkInfo: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let id = this.$route.params.id;
    chk.where("partId", "==", id).get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                var data = doc.data();
                chkInfo.push({ chk_id: doc.id, d: data.detail, s: data.sequence, status: data.status });
            });
        })
      }
  }
</script>
```

If you really can't modify the template, you should declare it as global function outside vue instance.

Comment: I already use that method on the whole project, I cannot change the other parts at this moment actually. Btw, I also tried to pass a value to the function but still, the function is not trigger.

Comment: Can you show how you render that html in the component?

Comment: sure, wait a moment I update the post. Already updated =)

Comment: Since html is rendered as plain html, the function will not be called as it's not inside vue instance. I think you need to move that inside the template. The way to get it called the way you doing is to create it as a global function outside vue instance

Comment: Ohh in that case then I move out the function from Vue. Thanks for give me an idea!